# How to get the list of values of different classes for a feature?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe. I want to get the list of all values of different classes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(3, 1),
                    (4, 3),
                    (6, 2),
                    (7, 2),
                    (2, 3),
                    (4, 2),
                    (4, 1),
                    (1, 3),
                    (6, 3),
                    (8, 1)],
                    columns=['Feature', 'Class'])
```

In the above example, I have three classes, namely 1, 2, and 3. I would like to get the output of all different lists of values in a class. The output can be following:

```
Class 1: [3, 4, 8]
Class 2: [6, 7, 4]
Class 3: [4, 2, 1, 6]
```

Comment: `df.Feature.groupby(df.Class).apply(list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply:

```py
classes = df.groupby('Class')['Feature'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```py
>>> classes
Class
1       [3, 4, 8]
2       [6, 7, 4]
3    [4, 2, 1, 6]
Name: Feature, dtype: object
```

You can print them like this:

```py
>>> for class_number, items in classes.items():
...     print(f'Class {class_number}: {items}')
...
Class 1: [3, 4, 8]
Class 2: [6, 7, 4]
Class 3: [4, 2, 1, 6]
```

---

If you want to get all *unique* values, try this:

```py
unique = df.groupby('Class')['Feature'].unique()
```

Comment: `df.groupby("Class").agg(list)`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069846/13552470) great answer, you can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) method along with the [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) method to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([(3, 1),
                   (4, 3),
                   (6, 2),
                   (7, 2),
                   (2, 3),
                   (4, 2),
                   (4, 1),
                   (1, 3),
                   (6, 3),
                   (8, 1)],
                  columns=['Feature', 'Class'])

print(df.groupby('Class')['Feature'].apply(list))
```

Output:

```
Class
1       [3, 4, 8]
2       [6, 7, 4]
3    [4, 2, 1, 6]
Name: Feature, dtype: object
```

But if you want to loop through the class numbers one by one, a more intuitive way would be to use the [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) property like so:

```
print(df.loc[df['Class'] == 1])
```

Output:

```
   Feature  Class
0        3      1
6        4      1
9        8      1
```

Or include the `"Feature"` column to get:

```
print(df.loc[df['Class'] == 1]["Feature"])
```

Output:

```
0    3
6    4
9    8
Name: Feature, dtype: int64
```